# Serializing objects Codename One

Tags: codenameone

How do I serialize an object in order to make a customizable Parse initialization? Like:

```
//Simple text fields to get info
TextField url = new TextField();
TextField appid = new TextField();
TextField clientkey = new TextField();
```

then I put all in an object e.g:

```
Myclass object = new Myclass();
object.url = url.getText();
object.appid = appid.getText();
object.clientkey = clientkey.getText();
```

so I put it here, but before it needs to be serialized in order to keep its values after my app get restarted.

```
//After serialization
Parse.initialize(object.url, object.appid, object.clientkey);
```

In this way I can set my Parse initialization by my application instead.
I'd appreciate to see an example of serialization in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for serialization.  You're on your own.

Comment: Of course there is, but not actually using the same way as in java.io.Serializable, Codename One has their own ways to do it by their framework, so my question is how to do that by using Codename One framework, like in this example: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Storage.html
However I can't figure out a way to implement that in my case or even better if there is another way I'd like to see an example in my case.

Comment: The storage class is a way to store some bits in the local file system.  It doesn't help you decide what bits to save, which is what the standard java class Serializable does.

Comment: Codename1 has an interface Externalizable but you have to write your own externalize/internalize methods for the objects, there's no default implementation.

Answer (score 2):

When you store an object in parse it's saved locally so you don't need to serialize.

FYI Codename One supports the `Externalizable` interface to serialize objects in binary form. It also supports seamless externalization for [object properties](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/properties-are-amazing.html). The latter don't work with Parse AFAIK.

Comment: Can you show me an example for parse object storage for 3 strings such as url, appid and clientkey as I need them in my question example.

Comment: If you just invoke the server storage parse is supposed to seamlessly save locally if it can't connect.